# Multisite CMS in Laravel 5.1, one backend, same server, folders, assets & general structure concerns

Tags: laravel, content-management-system, laravel-5, assets, laravel-5.1

I´m just starting to learn Laravel and decided to build a new version of my current CMS system with Laravel 5.1. It will be a CMS with one admin and multiple sites.

I figured that since each site will be using different assets in the public folder, I would need to create different public folder for each app.

So instead of 'app/public', I have 'app/sites/Admin' with it´s own unique css files, images, etc. I´ve already built the Admin part, with it´s proper views, assets, models, controllers, etc, and it´s (apparently) working fine.

So when I started developing the "Time da ANABB" site, I followed the same process: created it´s own controllers in it´s own folder, it´s own views, etc.

But when I tried it out, the route does point to the proper view, but all my links to CSS, imgs, etc are broken. When I output {!! public_path() !!} on this site´s view, I get it point to "C:\Users\Martin\Dropbox\www\sistema-lengro\public"

So I´m not sure if I need to config a different public folder for each site (and if that´s the right thing to do!) or if I´m all wrong... Again, this is basically my first major project in laravel...

Some of my configs are:

I´m using Virtual Hosts and route groups to address each request, as in:

`//Admin Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'domain' => 'dev.sistema', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function () { Route::get('admin', function () { return view('admin.painel'); }); }`

//Site Route::group(['domain' => 'dev.timedaanabb', 'namespace' => 'TimeDaAnabb'], function () { Route::get('/', function () { return view('sites.timedaanabb.pages.home'); }); });

I´ve also created a controllers folder for each, like 'app/Http/Controllers/Admin' and 'app/Http/Controllers/TimeDaAnabb'. For the Models, will be 'app/Admin/Users.php', for example.

I don´t know if that´s the best approach, but it´s working fine so far.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe setting up virtual hosts would solve your problem.

Comment: It´s set already, that´s not the problem...

Comment: You can't have multiple apps with the same public folder, because each app has a different app_path.

Comment: I´m pretty sure you can! Take a look at this package:
https://github.com/laraflock/multi-tenant

The only thing though, is that I´m trying to learn the most out of laravel, so I was really avoiding using third party packages and trying to do things on my own...!

Comment: You still have to create routes, css for each app according to the package.   Each website has its own folder on disk, allowing:

seperation of routes, templates, translations etc
custom files (media, themes and packages)

Comment: But that´s exactly what I want. One core CMS deliverying multiple sites, each one with it´s own assets

Comment: If you setup multiple sites on your server all pointing to the same public folder, you should be able to write routes for one site and then the other by specifying the `domain`.